# Should I shrink multiple factor variables into one?

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, feature-engineering

```
* NEW CAR: Purpose for this credit/application? (Binary)
  + 0: No
  + 1: Yes
* USED CAR: Purpose for this credit/application? (Binary)
  + 0: No
  + 1: Yes
* FURNITURE: Purpose for this credit/application? (Binary)
  + 0: No
  + 1: Yes
* RADIO/TV: Purpose for this credit/application? (Binary)
  + 0: No
  + 1: Yes
* EDUCATION: Purpose for this credit/application? (Binary)
  + 0: No
  + 1: Yes
* RETRAINING: Purpose for this credit/application? (Binary)
  + 0: No
  + 1: Yes
```

So these are some of the variables I have for a new dataset. Since they are related to the purpose behind loan applications, would it be wise to group them under one variable that I could call "Purpose"?

I plan on running a Random Forest Model. I want to try out both ways and I probably will as soon as I conduct an analysis as it is.

To be clear, I've already checked that two variables don't hold a "Yes" in the same row number.

**Is there any downside to creating ONE vector/variable that looks like when creating decision trees?:**

```
c("NEW_CAR", "RADIO/TV", "RETRAINING", "FURNITURE", "USED_CAR", "USED_CAR", "NEW_CAR")
```

I'm worried that there is a major downside as each current variable is binary and a tree can only split into two nodes. Perhaps it doesn't make a difference considering that there could be multiple nodes with a choice between the current variables.

I'm new. Thank you.

Thank You.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that any combination of the binary variables may be present, but having them all as a single variable only allows one to be true at a time.

Comment: There are no combinations, thankfully. Do you happen to know how I could check for combinations? I've done so, manually, but that's not optimal. Ideally, just be able to find observations with any combination at all, rather than specific ones.